# How to create a Simple Build Script for Visual Studio from the Command Line?

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2012, cmd, build-script

I have a lot of Visual Studio Project Solutions in multiple directories (all with the extension .sln) and I want to write a simple batch script that will automatically build all solutions listed in the batch file.

I am able to manually build a solution by starting up the `Visual Studio Command Prompt` (which is just a command-line instance with the following command executed

`"%comspec%" /k "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86`

After which I then build the project by calling:

`devenv "path\to\solutionFile\projectSolution1.sln" /build Debug`

This will build the project (assuming the project does not have errors) and I rinse and repeat for each project I want built.

**However** when I have the following in a batch file called `build.bat`:

```
"%comspec%" /k "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86  
echo "Starting Build for all Projects with proposed changes" 
echo . 
devenv "path\to\solutionFile\projectSolution2.sln" /build Debug
devenv "another\path\to\solutionFile\projectSolution3.sln" /build Debug
devenv "yet\another\path\to\solutionFile\projectSolution4.sln" /build Debug
echo "All builds completed."
pause
```

**The batch script only executes the first line**, and waits until I type in `exit` before executing the others. My understanding of this based on the research I have done on batch files and all the StackOverflow questions is that `cmd` actually invokes another instance of itself that executes `vcvarsall.bat` to set up the build environment.

This will not work as typing `exit` kills that instance with `devenv` set up and the commands after that cannot execute as `devenv` is not a recognized command (since the exported path will not exist anymore)

**In short**, how can this be achieved (passing in the rest of the commands to the cmd instance with `devenv` defined) in a single batch file? I understand this isn't a robust way (and there are a lot of tools that do this) of invoking builds but I'm just hoping to have one batch script to automate the manual work of individually calling these projects.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the solution, as noted by Jimmy, one needs to remove the environment variable `%comspec%` as that is a shortcut to CMD.exe.

However, just removing `"%comspec" /k` will cause a CMD instance to open and then exit after a second. I also previously tried the `call` function which created a separate CMD instance when used with `%comspec%`

**The solution is to** add `call` in front of the first line, and remove `%comspec`

Here is the final batch file that got things working as intended.

```
@echo OFF 
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
echo "Starting Build for all Projects with proposed changes"
echo .  
devenv "path\to\solutionFile\projectSolution2.sln" /build Debug 
devenv "another\path\to\solutionFile\projectSolution3.sln" /build Debug 
devenv "yet\another\path\to\solutionFile\projectSolution4.sln" /build Debug 
echo . 
echo "All builds completed." 
pause
```

Note that `@echo OFF` tells the batch script to not echo out the commands (such as that call command) into the terminal (errors and warnings will still be shown, however)

Comment: I tested the script and noticed that the `call "..." x86` line should be on a new line. I tried to edit the code, but SO requires at least 6 character changes... :-(

Comment: @MaartenDocter good catch, thanks! I've updated it. Code formatting gets fudged when I copy paste through a vm. :(

Comment: For Visual Studio 2022 Preview, the command is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat`

Answer (score 2):

If this is already in a batch script, then this line:

```
"%comspec%" /k "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
```

Probably should just be `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86`

Why?  `%comspec%` is just an environment variable shortcut to cmd.exe, so as you saw, it's launching a new instance of cmd with the /k option specified (which if you run `cmd /?` says `Carries out the command specified by string but remains`).  You don't care about it remaining, you don't even want a new cmd.exe when you're already running your batch file.