# How to fix MsBuild error - MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741510

Tags: msbuild

I am building a C++ project with configuration Release|x64 via MsBuild using the command:

```
set MSBUILD_EXE_PATH="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe"
%MSBUILD_EXE_PATH% /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 "!SOURCES_DIR!\mySolution.sln"
```

and I am getting the **error:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.Targets(152,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741510.
```

What does it mean and how can I fix it?
Thank you

Comment: Do you have your environment setup correctly for C++, did you call vsdevcmd.bat first? (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53041391/how-to-build-c-c-c-solutions-using-msbuild-and-vs2017-compiler-via-batch-f for example for VS2017 but same principle applies for other versions)

Comment: I tried you suggestion. I added a call to the script: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" and also tried to run it with a parameter x64, but it didn't help and I am still getting the same error